# Daemon Thread in Daemon service

Tags: python, python-2.7

### The Summary

I'm writing a daemon to run as a Linux service.  It communicates with an API (which I'm also writing but isn't part of the problem,) gets data, does stuff with that data, then feeds the newly munged data back to the API.

When I issue the `script.py start` command, it works just fine.  The daemon process starts the script and the daemon Threads kick off and run.

What doesn't happen is when I issue the `script.py stop` command, the daemon Threads keep running.  The stopping of the main thread (the one kicked off by `script.py start`) doesn't stop the daemon Threads.

I can still see them running with `ps ux`.  And they keep running until manually killed.

### The Question

How do I get my `script.py stop` to kill the daemon Threads as well as the main thread launched by the `daemon` module?

### The Details

More in depth: It's a network device polling engine with a server/agent model.  This is the agent side.

There are two daemon threads:

- GetterThread
- PutterThread

There are up to 15 worker threads of class `WorkerThread` that can be launched to either ping or SNMP poll the inventory of a given IP address.  They merely launch a sub-process that does the actual pinging or polling.

There are three data Queues:

- ping_request_queue
- poll_request_queue
- result_queue

The whole thing is wrapped up in a custom class called `App` that is controlled by the `daemon` module

## GetterThread

```
class GetterThread(threading.Thread):
    """ This thread is responsible for fetching the ping and poll lists from the server and dropping them into the
    appropriate queue """
    server = None                   # type: Server
    ping_request_queue = None       # type: Queue.Queue
    poll_request_queue = None       # type: Queue.Queue

    def __init__(self, server, ping_request_queue, poll_request_queue):
        """
        Create the Thread

        :param Server server: The server to use
        :param Queue.Queue ping_request_queue:
        :param Queue.Queue poll_request_queue:
        """

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ctl = ThreadController()
        self.server = server                                # type: Server
        self.ping_request_queue = ping_request_queue        # type: Queue.Queue
        self.poll_request_queue = poll_request_queue        # type: Queue.Queue

    def run(self):
        while self.ctl.run:
            if not self.server.online:
                sleep(30)
                self.server.check_in()
                continue
            sleep(1)
            ping_list, poll_list = self.server.get_lists()
            for r in ping_list:
                req = PingRequest.decode(r)
                self.ping_request_queue.put(req)
            for r in poll_list:
                req = PollRequest.decode(r)
                self.poll_request_queue.put(req)
        self.ctl.remove()
```

## PutterThread

```
class PutterThread(threading.Thread):
    """ This thread is responsible for picking up results from the results_queue and sending them to the server """
    server = None           # type: Server
    q = None                # type: Queue.Queue

    def __init__(self, server, result_queue):
        """
        Create a thread to put the results on the server

        :param Queue.Queue result_queue:
        """

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ctl = ThreadController()
        self.server = server            # type: Server
        self.q = result_queue

    def run(self):
        while self.ctl.run:
            if not self.server.online:
                sleep(30)
                self.server.check_in()
                continue
            sleep(1)
            if self.q.not_empty:
                result = self.q.get()
                if isinstance(result, Request):
                    if result.stage == Request.PINGED:
                        """ Send the ping results """
                        f = self.server.send_ping_results
                        lmsg = 'Sent ping result for request {}'.format(result.uuid)
                    elif result.stage == Request.POLLED:
                        f = self.server.send_poll_results
                        lmsg = 'Sent poll result for request {}'.format(result.uuid)
                    else:
                        continue
                    f(result)
                    logging.debug(lmsg)
                else:
                    logging.info('Bad request in queue: {!r}'.format(result))
        self.ctl.remove()
```

Both the getter and putter thread instances are set as daemons.

I'm running the whole script as a daemon:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pidfile_path = "/var/run/project/poller.agent.pid"
        self.logfile_path = "/var/log/project/poller.agent.log"
        self.handler = logging.FileHandler(self.logfile_path)

    def run(self):

        result_queue = Queue.Queue()
        ping_request_queue = Queue.Queue()
        poll_request_queue = Queue.Queue()

        getter_thread = GetterThread(self.server, ping_request_queue, poll_request_queue)
        getter_thread.setName('GetterThread')
        getter_thread.setDaemon(True)

        putter_thread = PutterThread(self.server, results_queue)
        putter_thread.setName('PutterThread')
        putter_thread.setDaemon(True)

        worker_threads = []

        max_threads = {
            'ping': 5,
            'poll': 10,
        }

        thread_defs = [
            ('ping', ping_request_queue, result_queue),
            ('poll', poll_request_queue, result_queue)
        ]

        while True:
            if ping_request_queue.not_empty or poll_request_queue.not_empty:
                for thread_def in thread_defs:
                    thread_type, input_queue, output_queue = thread_def
                    thread_count = min(input_queue.qsize(), max_threads.get(thread_type))
                    for x in range(thread_count):
                        t = WorkerThread(*thread_def)
                        t.setName('WorkerThread-{}-{:02n}'.format(thread_type, x)
                        worker_threads.append(t)
                        t.start()
            sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    daemon_runner = runner.DaemonRunner(app)
    daemon_runner.daemon_context.files_preserve = [app.handler.stream]
    daemon_runner.do_action()
```